# Command line: merge and keep all info from the two files

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, unix, shell

How to merge and keep all info from the two files as such ?

```
$ cat file1.txt           
apple
cool
dude
flan

$cat file2.txt           
apple
ball
cool
dude
elephant
```

for a result as such :

```
$cat result.txt
apple
ball
cool
dude
flan
elephant
```

Basically, it takes all entries from the two files except duplicates.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Merge and keep all info from the two files

Use the following command:

```
diff -DNAME file1.txt file2.txt | awk '!/NAME/' > result.txt
```

You must make sure that the string `NAME` does not appear in either of the files (otherwise use some other string that does not appear).

Example:

```
$ cat file1.txt
apple
cool
dude
flan
$ cat file2.txt
apple
ball
cool
dude
elephant
$ diff -DNAME file1.txt file2.txt | awk '!/NAME/' > result.txt
$ cat result.txt
apple
ball
cool
dude
flan
elephant
```

Note that the lines are in the same order as per your requirement.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Linux command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/)
- [awk gawk Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/awk.html)
- [diff Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/diff.html)

Comment: Thanks but I cannot sort my file. is there another way ?

Comment: @VirginieVélitchkoff So how are the entries in result.txt meant to be ordered? Your example results file does not seem to follow any pattern.

Comment: This is just a test case. My purpose is the following: I worked on two different version of the same files. I added some things here and there in one and others in the second. I want to have all info and new infos of both file in one. I thought of $diff -u file1.txt file2.txt but flan would be missed. 
the order is because, I can't read my document in disorder, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @VirginieV Answer rewritten to match your unusual requirement.

Comment: @VirginieV Great! Please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).

Answer (score 1):

Simeplest solution I could think of:

```
sort -u file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: The OP cannot use `sort`. See the comments on my answer for the reasons why.

Comment: Still the OP *neglected* to update the question. For "all entries from the two files except duplicates" this answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff --old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='%L' file1.txt file2.txt
```